# How to run java program using another java program?

Tags: java

I am using below code,

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runTime.exec("javac C:\\testDemo\\Demo.java");
p.waitFor();

Process p2= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Demo.class");
p2.waitFor();
```

it is creating a .class file, but its unable to run this program. do i need to do any change in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Demo.class");` method?

Comment: Why not run the other programs main method?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`java Demo.class`

To:

`java C:\\testDemo\\Demo`

Comment: yeah i checked with that as well, still it's giving error like, Error: Could not find or load main class Demo.class

Comment: @Sam - Check the edit.. Give the full path, it will work.. unless ofcourse your `javac` fails. You should really read the output of the process doing `javac`.

Comment: @Sam on that case you should post the code of Demo.java

Comment: You should also try to manually run `java C:\\testDemo\\Demo`